# Buffer calculation in AudioHardwareALSA::getInputBufferSize(...)

Tags: android, audio, alsa

I'm looking at getInputBufferSize(...) function in AudioHardwareALSA.cpp and it returns hardcoded the value of 320. My question is: How is this value calculated?

I've done some pre-cals but still there are some questions.

```
sample_rate = 8000
format = S16_LE = 2 bytes/sample
period_time = 10000 us (guessing)
buffer_size = 2 * period_size
period_size = period_time * bytes/sec
buffer_size = 2 * (0.01 * sample_rate * 2) = 320 bytes.
```

I can't find the period_time in the code, so one question is: where is it defined or is just a rough calculation?

I'm also trying to add some more sample rates i.e 16000 and 32000 (later maybe more). How to calculate the right minimum buffer size? Is the delay always 10 ms for all the sample rates?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Google implemented NB-AMR encode to start with. later they added support for AAC. In the case of NB-AMR, the frame size is 320 bytes. 
You may be aware that for NB-AMR:
    sampling rate = 8000 samples / sec
    frame duration = 20ms 
    sample size = 2 bytes
    channels = mono
So, each frame contains
    8000 samples / sec * 0.02 sec * 2 bytes / sample / channel * 1 channels = 320 bytes

For AAC, these parameters are different and hence the framesize

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. That makes sense for the framesize, but the function is supposed to give the buffer size. From the alsa-project site, the buffer size must be larger (at least 2x) the period size. That's why I was wondering why not return 2 x framesize. Maybe this function should have some comments that says it is returning the frame size i.s.o buffer.
Anyways, thanks for taking your time to answer my question.